# C# List<T> Contains test

Tags: c#, list

Is this kind of if-testing necessary when removing an item?

```
if (_items.Contains(item))
{
    _items.Remove(item);
}
```

And, what about this test?

```
if (!_items.Contains(item))
{
    _items.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just read the documentation and/or try it?  Seems like a simple thing to find out.

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with asking the question on Stackoverflow, even though you're right that reading the documentation is always a good reflex to have. Answers here can also provide additional insight that can be interesting for him (like the mention to Hashset in the second answer).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't have to test to remove.  Remove() will return false if it didn't remove anything.

If you don't want duplicate items in your list you can test, before adding.  Otherwise, you'll have duplicates.

See also: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx

Comment: If you don't want duplicates, you shouldn't test; you should use a collection that doesn't let you have duplicates. Otherwise, you don't have thread-safety.

Comment: Assuming thread safety is an issue. If it is, you also need to be sure your collection class is thread-safe (I'm guessing MS's may be, idk).

Answer (score 7):

You could also use a HashSet<T> if you want to be able to Add() an item multiple times and have it only exist in the collection once, without checking Contains() first.